# What does the word "grafting" mean here?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Please help me figure the meaning of the word "grafting" in the following sentence from a description of the game "Love Island The Game":

You'll choose outrageous outfits, play cheeky challenges, and get grafting.

I know the lexical meanings of the word graft, but am not sure it they fit here.

For more context, here is another text from a different source:

Then the boys arrive. First up is generic hunky whiteboy Jake, who has nothing about him, so I refuse to make eye contact with him. Next in is Mason, a musician and underwear model from Romford, who looks like Marcel from last year’s show, so I get grafting on him and use all the flirt options.

Comment: Sounds like [British slang](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/graft) meaning 'working'. Romford is in Essex.

Comment: It's hard to describe how funny "underwear model from Romford" sounds to English ears. Essex is England's Jersey Shore.